# Is it no longer relevant to know concrete controller type in Spring 4.x?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am a bit confused about **Controller Types** in Spring 4.x MVC since I am coming from Spring 3 and trying to update myself for 4.x.

Going through [Spring Current MVC Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc)

Section **21.3 Implementing Controllers**

> Spring implements a controller in a very abstract way, which enables
>   you to create a wide variety of controllers.

and then in section **21.3.1 Defining a controller with @Controller**

In first para,

> Spring does not require you to extend any controller base class or
>   reference the Servlet API. However, you can still reference
>   Servlet-specific features if you need to.

so I have a single controller annotation - `@Controller` and at the same time I have been given liberty to create a wide variety of controllers , how is that possible?

I mean how do I or Spring know about actual / concrete type of Controllers by annotating a class by `@Controller` or is it no longer relevant to know?

is it decided by the actual code ( kind of mapping and methods defined ) of Controller class?

Comment: The type of the class is irrelevent for spring to handle a class as a controller. Spring will map a class as a controller (map http request) when a class has the annotation @Controller if you use annotation EnableWebMvc on configuration class or <mvc:annotation-driven/>
in xml.

Comment: Thanks, so knowledge or explicit mention about `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController` or `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController` not needed , right?

Comment: If you use Controller classes that described by annotation, you don't need to inherit this classes from `AbstractController` or `MultiActionController`. Spring will prepare bean definitions of such classes based on annotations.